# Sublime Text - Search and Replace

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

In the code above how can I search for `editEntidadeXXX` on the name attribute and then insert this value on the id attribute?

Something like `editEntidade(\w)+` will found the names but it is possible to insert that values on the edit attribute?

```
<div class="control-group column-group horizontal-gutters">
    <label class="large-15 small-100 content-right" for="editEntidadeRua">Rua</label> 
    <div class="control large-40 medium-40 small-100">
        <input type="text" id="editEntidade" name="editEntidadeRua" value="<?php echo html_escape($entidadeValues['rua']) ?>">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group column-group horizontal-gutters">
    <label class="large-15 small-100 content-right" for="editEntidadeCodpostal">Código Postal</label> 
    <div class="control large-10 medium-10 small-100">
        <input type="text" id="editEntidade" name="editEntidadeCodpostal" value="<?php echo html_escape($entidadeValues['codpostal']) ?>">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find What:

```
id="editEntidade"(\s+)name="editEntidade(\w+)"
```

Replace With:

```
id="editEntidade$2" name="editEntidade$2"
```